# How do I center drawn things in JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe

I am trying to Center an oval drawn with `JFrame` & `Color` but I don't know how I would do this.

I know that I can get get the width by using `Jframe#width()` but I don't know how to do this in the method `paintComponent`, where I draw my circle. If I add a parameter to the Method, JFrame it doesn't work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
public class AU19b extends JPanel{
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawOval(10,10, 50, 50);
   }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Sebastians GUI");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(400, 250);
        f.add(new AU19b());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just do getWidth() in the paintComponent method? This will call that method in the JPanel that AU19b extends, and there's your width. Btw., I think the paintComponent override method needs to be public, not protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to draw a circle with radius 50.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class AU19b extends JPanel{

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.RED);

        int radius = 50;

        g.drawOval(getWidth()/2 - radius,getHeight()/2 - radius, 2*radius, 2*radius);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Sebastians GUI");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(400, 250);
        f.add(new AU19b());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if any border has been added to the JPanel, then the drawing might not be centered in the panel if the border is not symmetrical. Also, as @Dreamspace President stated, the paintComponent() method must be public,.